# How to add tracks to a specific playlist by a keyboard shortcut in MediaMonkey?

Tags: audio, mediamonkey

I can right click a track and add it to a playlist. Yet I find the nested context menu bothersome. Is there a way to add a keyboard shortcut for this action?

(I know that there is a right click context menu on most keyboards. Yet it's the context menu itself I do not want to deal with.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by installing the add-on from Zvezdan available from the MediaMonkey forum thread [Add CurrPlaying/Selected to Playlist](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=64062).

---

### Steps Involved

1. Download the MediaMonkey installation package
2. Install according to the posted instructions
3. Configure the playlist you want to send currently selected tracks to (you can change this later)
4. Configure your hotkeys or use the default per the quote below

> The default hot-key for adding the currently playing track is Ctrl+Alt+Shift+0 and for the selected track(s) is Alt+Shift+0. However, you could change the hot-keys in the Tools | Options dialog box on the General > Hotkeys sheet specifying General: Execute script: Add * Track to Playlist in the Action combo box with the wanted hot-key pressed in the Hotkey box. You should also use that step if you want to make the hot-key global since the default hot-keys are valid only when used inside of the program.